# Error on creating list Field in Schema?

Tags: 2013, schema, keyword

I am trying to create a Schema with a list field for selecting a Keyword from a Category but when I am saving this Schema I am getting following error in the UI, I am using SDL Tridion 2013.

> Error in line 1 position 494. 'EndElement' 'List' from namespace 'http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/R6' is not expected. Expecting element 'Entries'.
>   Unable to save new schema

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit:** Chrome 38 reversed the changes and so a hotfix is no longer required. Simply update your Chrome instead.

Original answer:

Are you using Chrome? They recently released an update which broke some functionality, resulting in the kind of error you describe.

There is a hotfix for 2013 SP1 ([CME_2013.1.0.87924](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/images/CME_2013.1.0.87924_tcm89-21334.zip)) and 2011 SP1-HR2 ([CME_2011.1.2.87923](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/images/CME_2011.1.2.87923_tcm89-21333.zip)) available on [sdltridionworld.com](http://www.sdltridionworld.com). If you aren't using either version, you probably need to use a different browser for now.

Comment: thanks when I use different browser this error is not coming

Comment: Lately, Chrome and its updates, are giving a lot of problems.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit of a problem when they decide to not support something that's in the DOM standard because too few people are using it according to their metrics :) Hopefully this trend does not continue.

Comment: I had faced a similar issue in SDL Tridion 2011 in Chrome browser version 36 and 37. All issues related chrome browser was resolved in version 38. We did not apply any hotfixes. 

Upgrade your chrome browser to stable version 38 and try again.

Comment: That's correct. Chrome 38 reversed the changes they had made and so the Tridion hotfix is no longer required.